# How to get a new id when there is no records in database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, methods, return

when I run this method GetNewID() it should return max Product_Id + 1 from database. So if the Max Product_Id in the database is 20 the next one should be 21. 
That's working fine.

But what's not working is when there is no records in database and it's null. I've tried with a different select statement and some if-statements but didn't work. Do you have any ideas on how I can solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
    public static int GetNewId()
    {
        string selectString = @"SELECT MAX(Product_Id) FROM Products";
        try
        {
            newId= 0;
            connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmdSelectLastId = new SqlCommand(selectString, connection);

            newId = Convert.ToInt32(cmdSelectLastId.ExecuteScalar());

        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return newId + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Use autoincrement [`IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) values instead. You are creating an inefficient race condition otherwise. Apart from that: `COALESCE` is your friend.

Comment: I think it would be better to create a sequence and trigger in database which should take care of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the query return zero instead of null when there are no records:

```
string selectString = @"SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Product_Id),0) FROM Products";
```

Comment: +1 for doing want the OP wants - however the OP should probably use their SQL server's identity construct (IDENTITY, AUTO_INCREMENT, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Product_Id), 0) FROM Products
```

However, the way in which you're implementing this is potentially fraught with danger. For example, have you considered two concurrent processes running through this code one immediately after the other, but before the record for the first has been inserted into the database?

Depending upon your database, you may be better off using an automatically generated ID, or a GUID.

Comment: Easier than I thought, working fine now! I think it's no problem at the moment, but I'll think on that for later projects!

Comment: @user1587603 Quite seriously, using an identity field is even easier. If you are going to follow a best practice, start following it sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Product_Id), 0) FROM Products
```

And you can add 1 within the query, too:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Product_Id), 0) +1 FROM Products
```